# How to add a custom class to GTRASLATE Plugin for JOOMLA?

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla, joomla-extensions

I need to add a custom class to the Gtraslate plugin because i have 2 modules with the same pluging and i need affect just one of them with a css rule. Any idea how add the custom class to the module? i tried change the default class in the module settings but it does not work, when i did the module stop working on the fronted.. soo how the hell can i change the default class by another one? i appreciate a lot the answers!In case i'm able to use javascrip for any idea [Gtraslate module default custom class which i tried to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tijQ0.png)

a solution to my ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.